Flutter Firebase without google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist
I have these packages inside my pubspec.yaml:
  firebase_core: ^2.25.5
  firebase_crashlytics: ^3.4.16
  firebase_analytics: ^10.8.7
  firebase_messaging: ^14.7.17

(using the most recent versions didn't change anything in my case)
I am trying to configure Flutter Firebase via
Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
);

instead of using values in google-services.json for Android and GoogleService-Info.plist for iOS.
My goal is to make a single entrypoint configurable with dart-define arguments or .env or something similar with all Api Keys, Bundle IDs, etc. (like DefaultFirebaseOptions generated by flutterfire_cli which can be modified using regular Dart syntax with platform checking, flavor checking and so on).  However it seems not possible to delete or even fill with some stub values those 2 Android and iOS config files because the FB plugin looks into them anyway during the initialization. So I came to conclusion that the options argument in Firebase.initializeApp method does almost nothing and initializing Firebase with "Pure Dart" method is useless if only you don't need multiple FB App instances inside you app (one of them is considered as "default" and the other should have original names passed by the name argument). flutterfire_cli can generate those config files along with firebase_options.dart but it looks like I have to keep managing google-services.json for Android and GoogleService-Info.plist for iOS just how it would be without Dart configuration.
You can ask me why do I need this?
The first answer is: "security". My customer wants the Firebase Api Keys to be hidden from the source code despite of information given in the official FB docs which says that these keys are designed to be public. Technically it is possible to write a script which would paste Api Keys into google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist but it seems awkward because those files are under source control and every developer in my team need them for launching the app.
The second answer is: convenience. It would be more comfortable to manage a single dart entrypoint instead of 2 platform entrypoints.
I've tried deleting google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.plist completely, and the app was failing to build.
I've tried to remove api key fields completely from them or replace to some invalid strings, and the app was crashing in runtime.
I looked the implementation of firebase_core's Firebase.initializeApp method and figured out that it starts with _initializeCore() which looks into native config files (source)

"every developer in my team need them for launching the app" - not necessarily true, if you have separate development and production environments.  Developers would only need the development project configuration to do their work, not the one for production.  You could even make everyone use their own individual project, completely insulating each other from their mistakes or malicious intent.

You're not required to use the given config files.  They are just provided as a convenience.  You can arrange for yourself to obtain the necessary config values, inject them into your app build, and pass them to initializeApp yourself in the optional FirebaseOptions argument.  From the linked API docs:
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  name: 'SecondaryApp',
  options: const FirebaseOptions(
    apiKey: '...',
    appId: '...',
    messagingSenderId: '...',
    projectId: '...',
  )
);

How you choose to get those values into your app is entirely up to you.
